# Pivot in SQL by Distinct Values

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, pivot

I have a table in BigQuery that looks like this:

| Team | Team Id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | AAAA |
| 2 | BBBBB |

And I want to get a table that looks like this

| Game Id | AAA | BBB |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 0 | 1 |

I've tried using `PIVOT`, but no such luck. Let me know if someone knows how to do this in SQL. Note that there are hundreds of team IDs so I need to dynamically define the team IDs in the pivot statement.

Answer (score 1):

Consider below approach

```
execute immediate (
select '''
  select * from your_table
  pivot(count(*) for team_id in (''' ||  list || "))"
from (
  select string_agg("'" || team_id || "'", "," order by team_id) as list
  from (select distinct team_id from your_table)
))
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]